# regex markdown match content between chapters

Tags: regex, markdown, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match all h2 chapters and the text contained between them (including subchapters).

For instance:

```
## chapter 1

text1 text1 text1
[Link text](http://link.com)
text2 text2 text2

### subchapter 1.1

subchapter text 

## chapter 2

bla bla bla
* a list 1
* a list 2

## Chapter 3


okokok
```

the above should return 3 matches: chapter 1, chapter 2, chapter 3 and chapter 1 should have two groups: "chapter 1" and "text1 ... subchapter text".

I came with the following solution involving positive and negative lookahead:

```
  /(?<=[#]{2}\s)([\w ]+)\n(.*?)(?=[#]{2})/gs
```

[example regex link](https://regex101.com/r/eRP2uT/1)

however it:

- misses last chapter (because there's no ending ##)
- misses subchapter because it matches two of the three #

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give you a hint in the right direction with the following:

https://regex101.com/r/93MI6A/1

basically by lifting the requirement for subchapters with the triple ### you can use:

```
((?!#){2}[\s\S])+
```

which matches all chapters (including the last one), once you have the matches for each single chapter it should be easy to strip out the title and get only the content with something like https://regex101.com/r/TuwO7R/1:

([a-z0-9 ]+[\n]{1})([\s\S]+)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^#{2}((?:([^#]{2})|[\n])+?)(?=^[#]{2}|\Z)
```

regex101 example:

https://regex101.com/r/pFy0I6/1